# Почему не все элементы удаляются из массива? JS, method pop()

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
function stringPop(str) {
  let stringResult = str.split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < stringResult.length; i++) {
    console.log(stringResult.length) // 
    stringResult.pop();
  }
  return stringResult;
}

console.log(stringPop("something"));
```

Должен в идеале выдать пустой массив. Однако выдает some. В чем проблема?

splice тоже такое выдает

Comment: А вы добавьте в `console.log` ещё вывод `i` и поймёте

Comment: Спасибо. Забыл что длина массива уменьшается

Comment: Если вам нужно опустошить массив, то проще написать `white(stringResult.length) { let val = stringResult.pop(); /* что-то делаем с val */ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А попробуйте в вашем коде выводить не только длину массива, но и `i`

```js
let res = "something".split("");

for (let i = 0; i < res.length /* ◄◄ */; i++) {
  res.pop();
  console.log(i, '<', res.length, '?', i < res.length /* ◄◄ */);
}

console.log('' + res);
```

`i` увеличивается, длина уменьшается.

Оба доходят до 4, условие `i < res.length`, оно же, `4 < 4` не выполняется и цикл прерывается.

---

При удалении элементов массива, «шагайте» по индексам справа налево:

```js
let res = "something".split("");

for (let i = res.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  res.pop();
  console.log(i, '?', res.length);
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Забыл что длина массива уменьшается